# Automaton NFA that include substring "aa" and "bb"

Tags: formal-languages, automata

$L=\left\{w \in\{a, b\}^{*} \mid a a \text { and } b b \text { are substrings in } w\right\}$ in NFA
I draw an intuitive automaton but I'm not sure it is the minimal one: [Here is my attempt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3B9w.png)
I hope someone can lead me.

Comment: You only need the string to contain $aa$ or $bb$. Once you get to either case, there is no need to transition from that state.

Comment: @JohnDouma: No, he needs the string to contain both $aa$ and $bb$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: I need both aa and bb

Comment: @RobertPiterson: I’ve not thought about minimality, but your automaton certainly works, assuming that the state at lower right is the unique acceptor state.

Comment: yes , it is the acceptor state but do you think is there a better sultion that uses less states?

Answer (score 4):

Please see whether the below DFA (which is of course also an NFA) works?

[image: DFA for accepting aa and bb]

Description: S is the starting state and AABB is the terminal state, which is also an accepting state. $\{A, B,AA,BB,AAB,BBA\}$ are all intermediary states.

Comment: I believe you have an issue in your AAB state and a similar one in BBA. Once you are in AAB, you need another "b" (with no other "a") in order to have the right substring. Similarly, in BBA, you need another "a" before you can add another "b." I believe your solution is correct if we just remove the loop to self on AAB and the loop to self on BBA.

Comment: thanks a lot PavanC

Comment: Solution now looks great.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for constructing the NFA algorithmically:

- Let's first construct the regular expression corresponding to the language $L$, simplest regular expression for $L$ is $((a+b)^{*}aa(a+b)^{*}bb(a+b)^{*})$
  $+ (( (a+b)^{*}bb(a+b)^{*}aa(a+b)^{*})$.
- Now use the construction algorithm to convert a regular expression to an NFA (the below figure shows the basic building blocks):

[image]

- Using the above buliding blocks, construct the NFA to accept the regular expression $(a+b)^{*}aa(a+b)^{*}bb(a+b)^{*}$, as shown in the next figure:

[image]

- Similarly, construct the NFA to accept $(a+b)^{*}bb(a+b)^{*}aa(a+b)^{*}$.
- Next, construct the final NFA to accept $((a+b)^{*}aa(a+b)^{*}bb(a+b)^{*})$
  $+ (( (a+b)^{*}bb(a+b)^{*}aa(a+b)^{*})$ from the above two NFAs:

[image: ![enter image description here]

- Using the above algorithm you can construct an NFA from a regular expression algorithmically (i.e., using a program).
- Now, you can always get a succinct DFA by state merging using another algorithm (e.g., by eliminating the ε-transitions by subset
  construction, etc.) to convert NFA to DFA, but the language recognized by both NFA and DFA remains the same.